# How to burn a data DVD in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, dvd-burning

I am trying to burn a data DVD (DVD+R) in Windows XP SP3 on a Dell desktop computer. The computer has a licensed copy of Nero 6.3. Nero indicates that an update to version 6.6 is available, but after following the link provided, it redirects me to the Nero website to purchase the upgrade. I'm not interested in doing this.

After creating a project in Nero 6.3, inserting a blank DVD+R and trying to start burning the data DVD, Nero indicates that I should insert an appropriate disk into the drive. It does not seem to detect the blank DVD+R.

I downloaded infrarecorder and cdrtfe from Sourceforge. Neither of these programs worked either. They both indicated that I should insert the correct media, with cdrtfe saying there is no disk in the drive. I tried with another blank DVD +R with the same effect.

I inserted a CDR containing data into the drive and the Windows read read this CDR without a problem. I have no reason to believe that the drive is faulty.

I am aware that Windows XP itself is not able to burn DVDs. However, it seems that three third-party software programs are not able to burn a data DVD in Window XP. The specifications provided in Nero indicate that DVD+R is compatible with the drive.

How can I burn a backup data DVD in Windows XP?

Comment: Have you ever succesfully burnt a DVD with that drive? Which model is the drive?

Comment: It happens that sometimes optical drives 'lose' one of their functions like in you example the "DVD function" while CDs work normally.

Comment: Do you have DVD+Rs of another brand to test? My current drive refuses to write to a specific brand of DVD+Rs that work in every other drive, while other brands work in this drive.

Comment: I would suggest Img Burn that can be found [here](http://www.imgburn.com/) Discovery - Put your drive / media to the test

Comment: @WalterMaier-Murdnelch: I can't be sure. I think I've burn CDRs there successfully before; not sure about DVDs.

Comment: @Bob: Thanks, I'll try that. The brand in question is a major brand which I've had success with before in other drives, so that's why I chose it. I have DVD+Rs from another major brand which I'll try.

Comment: I will also try an external USB writer.

Comment: Does windows shows the blank disk(DVD) in the drive or not?

Comment: Are you sure that desktop even has a DVD burner drive? Post the model number as asked before. It can be found in Device Manager.

Comment: Model number is HL-DT-ST DVD+-RW GWA4164B. Whether a blank disk is in the drive or not, Windows shows it with the same icon and text in My Computer.

Comment: @Bob: I tried with a different brand of DVD+R but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out a freeware such as CdBurnerXP or Burn4Free. 
See if the problem persists. Earlier versions of Nero may not be compatible with some hardware, while the freeware is frequently updated. Hope this solves it.
Another problem may be that your combo drive can READ DVDs but not write them.

Comment: *I downloaded infrarecorder and cdrtfe from Sourceforge. Neither of these programs worked either.* and *The specifications provided in Nero indicate that DVD+R is compatible with the drive.* Of course, it doesn't hurt to double check that the drive is able to write DVD+Rs, as opposed to reading or DVD-Rs.

Comment: @ch01ce: Thanks, but as I indicated in my question, I have already tried two other programs apart from Nero. I will try your suggestions though. The drive specifications indicate that it can write DVDs.

Comment: @Bob: The drive specifications indicate that it can re/write DVDs.

Comment: @SabreWolfy Could you mind sending a screenshot of the drive info in CdBurnerXP? PS: don't install the toolbars and whatnot they are trying to bundle with the software, unless you want to. There is an option not to do so.

Comment: @ch01ce: CdBurnerXP is the only program so far that actually allowed me to burn a data DVD. However, after it said that it successfully burnt the DVD, it showed up in Windows as a blank DVD. I looked at the surface and it looks like it has burnt the DVD, but it is blank in Windows.

Comment: @ch01ce: I checked the drive info box and it was too long to take a screenshot of. However, it showed that the drive can burn DVD-R, DVD+R, DVD+RW, etc. I am using DVD+R blank disks.

Comment: I used CdBurnerXP with an external USB CD/DVD drive and was able to burn the backup data DVDs. The DVD which CdBurnerXP burnt in the desktop machine did read on another machine. I'm not sure where the problem lies exactly and didn't test if that DVD now is readable in the desktop. I also didn't test any of the other programs with the external drive. I was able to burn using CdBurnerXP and the external drive.

Answer (score 2):

If have installed any software like Daemon Tools, verify that you did not enable the function to  mask writeable discs as read only, which is sometimes used to circumvent copy protection schemes that check the disc type when the disc is used in writers that can tell the difference. As a side effect, burning software then would also see only ROM media.

You might also want to try burning a disc using another OS to isolate the issue to either hardware or software. I suggest running a Linux live system like Knoppix. If you have two optical drives this should be no problem. Otherwise use the toram boot option or create a bootable pen drive.

Comment: I have not installed any software like Daemon Tools. The idea of using another OS is a good one. I will try to burn the DVD from Ubuntu or Debian booted from a USB drive.

Answer (score 1):

[Imgburn](http://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download) is free, small, easy and fast. Also available on http://ninite.com which i use to   install it on all pc's I configure, use it all the time for years now. As the name suggests can also work with images.

EDIT: as suggested here a word of explenation on ninite.com
You go to the site, select all the utilities you need installed (they are in categories), click "Get installer" and you download a very small program that you either run or save on your HD.
When you run this installer, no questions are asked, all programs are downloaded and installed as fast as can be. All with optimal configuration (no unnecessary tool bars on your browser etc). No searching for the most recent version, safe, fast, once you used it you won't revert. There are other such sites/services and i'm not sure ninite is the best, so go ahead and correct me. I'm not related to ninite in any way.

Comment: Next time remember to give the link of the official site or a link that directly indicates to user for download the software. Not a site that contains link for most usually software's. You are a user of SO and still don't use formatting. Keep in mind these things please.

Comment: @avirk, why would i not suggest downloading from ninite.com ? It's a lot safer, faster and easie than giging a link that changes in time. Also it installs all the progs you have chosen at once without interrupting. What can be bad about that ?. Please direct me to the policy on SE that syas what you suggest, otherwise i'm gonna restore my previous answer

Comment: I don't mind if you revert back the changes but official site is much better way to indicate user to download the stuff. The ninite.com is not familiar site for all user's and they will come back to ask you how to use it. Or you can tell them how to use that site in your answer and it will be good for them all the time.

Comment: That's much better now. You don't have need to explain that you are related or not to that site just it should be helpful for the user's in some way and I think it is. So you can remove that last line from your answer.

Comment: don't want to give the impression, that's all, this made me wonder if there are others like ninite (perhasp better) so i just made a question about it, just googling it doesn't give me user feedback

Comment: A good utility called [updatenotifier](http://cleansofts.org/view/update-notifier.html) I think you will like it.

Comment: i know it but don't use it, when you keep the installation package from ninite it does the same when you start it later, it updates the softs in it only when necessary, thanks for the suggestion. Over and out 8>)

Comment: Don't download ImgBurn like the other guy suggested. It contains malware. Same goes for Burn4Free. Be careful. Wodim on Cygwin is not malware and should do the job. Or Wodim on a bootable Linux USB device, or another open-source tool.